# How can I use a OnKeyPress event with no javascript when textbox is inside a AJAX UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have a asp:textbox inside an AJAX updatepanel. My goal is to be able to update other controls, such as a asp:listbox that is inside the same updatepanel, while I type in the asp:textbox. I can easily do this using javascript. However, I am under a restriction, that is, I cannot use javascript.

I am using asp.net and visual basic.
Is it possible to approach this without javascript?

Thanks,
Y_Y

Comment: Yeah, thats what I though. I'll leave the post to see if someone comes with some around solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without relying on javascript at all, but you can do it without writing any of your own javascript. ASP.Net webforms will insert javascript on it's own that you can't change that would make this possible.